# TS2345: Vue router-link failing on build when 'id' attribute is supplied

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-router

Bashing my head on this one. When I run `yarn run build` I receive a few of the following errors. They are all pointing to `<router-link>` elements that have an `id` attribute tied to them. VS Code does not point these out to me. Removing `id` fixes the issue, though some of my functions access these `router-link`'s via their `id`.

```
src/components/Header.vue:86:21 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ id: string; to: string; class: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps & VNodeProps & RouterLinkProps'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps & VNodeProps & RouterLinkProps'.

86        <router-link id="yourCardsLink" to="/account/cards" class="dropdown-link">
```

Updated packages, scoured GH PR's and Vue router docs.